# why C program cannot run multiple times?

Tags: c

when I ran following code , Initially it was run smoothly but after tenth eleventh time it was started taking garbage value and pritining output as -656 , +NAL , 0.0000 , -123000.000 etc?

```
  void main()

  {

       float x;
       scanf("%f",&x);
       printf("%f",x); 
       getch();
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the code in the question is the actual code you run? And more importantly, is the code in the question the *complete* and *actual* code? You don't have any include directives for header files?

Comment: I guess, its like you are printing the values of `getch()` in someplace of our code if thats not case your code should run smoothly without any error until the variable `x` is holding the value that it can store in the Code.

Comment: please include the complete code. It's pointless to guess unless you post the actual code here.

Comment: A note to the OP: If you post a question on SO (or, really anywhere), it's always good to be responsive to issues and questions and requests for clarifications that people make. As well as acknowledging answers (if they are correct by saying so and accepting them, otherwise saying that it didn't work). You don't ask questions in real-life to people and then just walk away without listening to what they have to say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here, but if the code in the question is your complete and actual code, then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because neither the `scanf` not the `printf` functions have been declared, which means that the compiler will *guess* what arguments they take, and in your case the compiler most likely guesses wrongly.

To fix this you need to include the header file where those functions are declared, so the compiler knows about them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```